# How to control KML icon drawing order, top to bottom

Tags: kml

I'm displaying many overlapping icons in a Google Earth tour. I'd like to control (or at least understand) the order in which the icons are drawn (which one shows on "top").  Thanks!

PS.  Non solutions attempted:  Using gx:drawOrder (it applies to overlays, but not icons).  Using AnimatedUpdate to establish the order chronologically.  Using the order in which you introduce the placemarks to establish their drawing order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Google Earth draws the features in groups by type: polygons, then ground overlays, followed by lines and point data where drawOrder is applied only within a group. ScreenOverlays are drawn last so they are always on top.

If you define gx:drawOrder or drawOrder on a collection of features, it only applies to the features of the same type (polygon and other polygons) not between different types.

That is the behavior if the features are clamped to ground. If features are at different altitudes then lower altitude layers are drawn first.

Note that the tilt angle affects the size of the icon and as the tilt approaches 90 degrees, the size of the icon gets smaller. The icon is at largest size when viewed straight-down with 0 degree tilt angle.

Comment: Very helpful!  Thank you!        Did you mean to be suggesting that drawOrder can order icons?  I wasn't able to acheive that and have read that GE doesn't support it.         I'll try to test Google Earth to see how it orders icons. Can you suggest any hypothesis to test?  Might an icon's size determine its drawing order?

Comment: drawOrder only allowed on overlays while gx:drawOrder can be on any geometry (poly, line, point, etc.). You can manually add gx:drawOrder to a Point with an icon in your KML.

Comment: I used **gx:drawOrder** after **Point** in setting up my **Placemarks**, as you suggested, and it worked like a charm in ordering my overlapping icons.  Thank you so much